# Как сделать путь активный, если находишся на другой ссылке angular

Tags: javascript, angular, spa, router

у меня есть кнопка, при нажатии на нее меня перенаправляет на другой компонент

`<div routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/offers"> <span class='text left'>Offers</span> </div>`

Ссылка становиться активной. Потом в этом компоненте тоже есть кнопка, которая перенаправляет меня на другой компонент

`<button class="button" routerLink="/profile/tutto">tutto</button>`

соответственно предыдущий путь "/profile/offers" уже не активный. Как сделать так, что бы он был активный при нажатии на вторую кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ)

Вы можете написать свой собственный, `routerLinkActiveа` затем использовать `[class.active]` для переключения активного класса.

```
public isActive(base: string): boolean {
return this.router.url.includes(base) ;}
```

И в html разметке добавить:

```
<div [class.active]="isActive('/profile/tutto-in-uno')" class="link order-20" 
routerLink="/profile/offers"> <span class='text left'>Offers</span></div>\
```

Вуаля, работает!